# Regex - Characters between deliminator

Tags: regex

I have the following URI

```
myapp://config/value?servers=https://192.168.251.1:8081&celldata=Y&https=Y&certificate=mylaptop.local:8080/certificate/clientcert.p12&certificatepassword=12345&allowgps=N
```

I wanted a nice efficient way of extracting the ports in the query string and thought I would try learning a bit of Regex in the process.

Using `:(.*?)(,|&|/)` is almost the desired result, but I don't want the deliminitors in the result, just the text between.

Can some please explain what I can do to achieve this?

Note: Please add an explanation to any expressions, as I've seen plenty of similar question with answers that don't have explanations.

Edit:

Expected outcome here, would be a `8081` and `8080` as the expression for extracting the port. It will be written in C# but the programming language is irrelevant, as the expression is global.

Comment: What language are you using? What's the expected result?

Comment: Can you show what exact results you're expecting? E.g. what strings do you want in the end?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url)

Comment: No it's not a duplicate. The URI I've given as an example could be any string that contains multiple URL's or server:port syntax's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
:(\d+)
```

That gives:

: - a literal colon

(\d+) - \d means digit, + means 1 or more, and brackets are for grouping ( group all the digits together)

You will then have to get the value from the 1st group, index 1 (not 0 )

Answer (score 0):

I'd do:

```
:(\d+)\b
```

where

`\d` stands for any digit one or more times
`\b` stands for word boundary